# What is the difference between "temper" and "disposition"?

Tags: differences

What is the difference between "temper" and "disposition" in reference to a person?

Comment: What research have you done already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following extract makes an interesting comparison between them, as for the definitions of each single term you can easily look them up in a [dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disposition).

***[Disposition, temper, temperament](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disposition)*** refer to the aspects and habits of mind and emotion that one displays over a length of time:

> - ***Disposition*** is the natural or prevailing aspect of one's mind as shown in behavior and in relationships with others: a happy disposition; a selfish disposition.
> - ***Temper*** sometimes denotes the essential quality of one's nature: a glacial temper;usually it has to do with propensity toward anger: an even temper; a quickor hot temper.
> - ***Temperament*** refers to the particular balance of emotions determining a person's character: an artistic temperament.

(Random House Dictionary)